# Dictionary of lists to list of tuples

Tags: python

```
t = {"Harvard": [43280, 51143], "Brown": [53419, 62680], "Columbia": [10968, 30257]}

t_pct_change = round((end - start)/start * 100, 2)

list_tuples = [(k, round((t[k][-1] - t[k][0])/t[k][0] * 100, 2)) for k in t for v in t[k]]
```

The end is the first index of the list and the start is the last index of the list. I want the result to be a list of tuples like

[('Harvard', 18.17), ('Brown', 17.34), ('Columbia', 175.87)]

My code iterates 3 times. How do I fix this or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does changing the line to `list_tuples = [(k, round((t[k][-1] - t[k][0])/t[k][0] * 100, 2)) for k in t]` give you what you want?

Comment: @Joe yes! The only problem is it prints the same info multiple times

Comment: It was "printing it" multiple times, but do you see the change I suggested?  Take out the `for v in t[k]` part.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to loop once over the dictionary using [`t.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques).

You can also [unpack](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples_unpack.asp) the values so you have nice meaningful names instead of indices.

```py
t = {"Harvard": [43280, 51143], "Brown": [53419, 62680], "Columbia": [10968, 30257]}
my_list = [(uni, round((end - start)/start * 100, 2)) for uni, (start, end) in t.items()]
print(my_list)
```

Expected output:

```
[('Harvard', 18.17), ('Brown', 17.34), ('Columbia', 175.87)]
```